# how to check for a element inside a row in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a table with several rows. One of the rows contains a table (without any id or class). I can iterate through each row. How can I determine whether the current row contain the table?

Comment: Could you paste some code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$("#outerTable tr").each(function()
{
   if($(this).find("table").length > 0){
    //this row contains the table
   }
});
```

Comment: Don't know enough about your structure to be more specific

Comment: Not sure if you need a reference to the actual row, or just need to know that a table exists in any of the rows?

Comment: I need to know if the current row has a table and if it does, skip this row

Answer (score 0):

you can check via has() method or using find() method.  [has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

```
if($('#yourTable tr').has('table'))
{ 
  //do something 
}
```

or

```
if($('tr').find('table').length>0)
{ 
  //do something 
}
```

Comment: I have the current row in a variable **row**. Should I use `$(row).has('table')`? and I dont have table id or class

Comment: @SudiptaRoy until unless you post your code, no one going to help you further